# Returning to Stage3D (Away3d) after StageVideo

Tags: mobile, video, air, stage3d, away3d

I'm having the well documented problem of StageVideo killing Stage3d, or at least overlaying a black layer above the Stage3D on mobile.

I've attempted some of the various solutions offered around the forums, including moving the viewport off screen, assigning the netstream to a normal flash video before closing. None of these seem to help.

Adobe's answer seems to be that is is working as it's designed and it's not a bug, specifically:

When using Stage3D, the user must call Context3D.present() to make the stage layer update. There is no independant update of the Stage, Context3D.present() drives the update of both the Stage and the Stage3D layers. This is necessary to achieve high performance. Workarounds include making all the Stage3D invisible and delaying the Context3D creation until you are going to start using it.”

From https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3186454

Away3d seems to use Stage3D managers in the core, and there is a present() function, which contains the important Context3D.present().

I'm having trouble trying to initiate this call, but can't see a way to access it.

Does anyone know if this is likely to work, and what the call might be?

Answer (score 0):

I got around it by using a native extension https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Video/